# Become first responder next available (not hidden) text field

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, swift4

I'm trying to make than a Swift 4 iPhone app that has various user input text fields go to the other text field when the user presses the Enter key. I did it with a switch statement, but now that I added the capacity of the text fields to hide or unhide according to a previous selection of the user, my switch statement is no longer working because I use the name of every text field. I couldn’t make it using tags.

I need the next text field for user input to change when the user taps Enter, taking account that some UITextFields will be hidden. 
I think that I have to arrange all the user input text in an arrangement, then use a while loop, but I'm not making any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add UITextFieldDelegate to your class
- in viewDidLoad() set delegate to self for each textfield like so:

  yourTextfield.delegate = self

Then add this function

```
// Textfield delegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch textField {
    case firstTextfield:
        firstTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        secondTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    case secondTextfield:
        secondTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        thirdTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    default:
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks I tried and it worked but I discover the IQKeyBoardManager and I installed, it resolved my problem too :)